# Remove Webcontent Control

Tags: uninstall

I installed this program to filter the content. It's not quite user friendly and I'd like to remove it completely. I installed and remove through software manager on Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm getting red triangle warning when I do `sudo apt-get update` and it's referring to this package.

removed http: from the message. It wouldn't let me post a reply.

```
W: GPG error: //packages.osrfoundation.org precise Release: The following >signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY >C4D0E34E9443F10F
W: Failed to fetch //ppa.launchpad.net/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch ://ppa.launchpad.net/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol/ubuntu>/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 0):

The command `sudo apt-get update` is not a method to remove software but it rereads the repositories to see if there are new versions available for the installed software. The particular error you get means that you don't have the corresponding key for that particular repository, furthermore it seems the computer is unable to find the ppa's at all. It is easy to solve these problems but it is not what your question is about.

You asked you to remove it, so then you have to issue the command:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge webcontentcontrol`

If you want to solve the missing key problem, open a terminal and enter this:

`$ keymissing=C4D0E34E9443F10F && \

gpg --keyserver wwwkeys.eu.pgp.net --recv-keys $keymissing && \

gpg --armor --export $keymissing | apt-key add - && apt-get update`

Comment: I'd like to get rid of the error. It still continues after applying above command.

Comment: I edited the method how to solve that into the answer above.

Comment: I'm still getting  the same errors.W: GPG error: http://packages.osrfoundation.org precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C4D0E34E9443F10F
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webcontentcontrol/webcontentcontrol/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.